# Viber displays numbers instead of name of senders, how can I restore the old setting on my Viber?

Tags: contacts, viber-messenger

My Viber shows numbers instead of names. Before, it shows sender names, now it show senders number unless I edit it.

How to restore to the previous setting?

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded a previous version (v18.5.1.0) and it resolves my issue.